# Array match in MongoDB lookup pipeline

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have two collections. One of artworks, the other of collections (album of multiple artworks).
Each artwork has a "collections" field that is an array in which the id of the collections to which it belongs is saved.

What I would like to do is get all the collections of a user and for each collection the first 4 artworks (to show a preview in the app).

However, this thing, which I thought was simple, turned out to be more complicated.

In a normal query I would do this:

```
artworkModel.find({
    collections: collection
})
```

However, in the aggregation pipeline, this does not work and so the solution I implemented was this:

```
[
  {$match: {
      author: author,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'artworks',
      as: 'previews',
      let: { collection: '$_id' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            collections: { $exists: true },
            $expr: { $in: ['$$collection', '$collections'] }, 
          },
        },
        { $sort: { date: -1 } },
        { $limit: 4 },
        { $addFields: { id: '$_id' } },
      ],
    },
  }
]
```

The problem is that I cannot accept this solution because it does not use, unlike the query above, the index on the "collections" field and therefore performs a full scan of the collection. Help is appreciated.

**EDIT: sample data**

artworks:

```
[
    {
      "_id": { "$oid": "612fa9541121d06014e7d9bc" },
      "collections": [
        { "$oid": "612fa9481121d06014e7d9b5" },
        { "$oid": "612fa9f6b2cc520a84e83dde" }
      ],
      "author": { "$oid": "5fe8fe53ff8d9dc25c9e3277" },
      "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vestibulum dolor id justo condimentum ",
      "type": "Text"
    },
    {
      "_id": { "$oid": "60eec90e787a0b320c514446" },
      "author": { "$oid": "5fe8fe53ff8d9dc25c9e3277" },
      "type": "Image",
      "asset": { "$oid": "60eec90e787a0b320c514441" },
      "collections": [{ "$oid": "612fa9f6b2cc520a84e83dde" }]
    },
    {
      "_id": { "$oid": "612fa9f2b2cc520a84e83db1" },
      "collections": [{ "$oid": "612fa9f6b2cc520a84e83dde" }],
      "author": { "$oid": "5fe8fe53ff8d9dc25c9e3277" },
      "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "type": "Text"
    },
    {
      "_id": { "$oid": "612549d4778270001862472f" },
      "author": { "$oid": "5fe8fe53ff8d9dc25c9e3277" },
      "type": "Video",
      "asset": { "$oid": "612549d4778270001862472a" }
    }
  ]
```

collections:

```
[
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "612fa9f6b2cc520a84e83dde" },
    "name": "Name",
    "author": { "$oid": "5fe8fe53ff8d9dc25c9e3277" },
    "itemsCount": 3,
  }
]
```

Comment: could you provide sample json data ?

Comment: there is no date field in the sample data, suppose that collections have 1 date field that you forgot to add i guess

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't realize it was used in the query. I have simplified the documents for better legibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bellow query does i think the same as your query.
Before running it create an index on `artworks.collections` (multikey index)

Query

- filters collections based on author
- joins with normal lookup using the index
- does a dummy join with 1 collection `[{}]` only to apply the pipeline
  that you want, its like a trick

Test it if you can and tell me if it worked and if its fast enough

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TbIt-5qRZtA)

```js
db.collections.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "author": {
        "$eq": "5fe8fe53ff8d9dc25c9e3277"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "artworks",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "collections",
      "as": "previews"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "dummy",
      "let": {
        "previews": "$previews"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$set": {
            "previews": "$$previews"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": {
            "path": "$previews"
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$previews"
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "date": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 4
        },
        {
          "$set": {
            "id": "$_id"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unset": [
            "_id"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "as": "previews"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. However, if I understand the code correctly, the aggregation first "populates" all the artworks and only then limits it to the first 4. So theoretically if the collection contains many artworks the query would have performance problems. Am I missing something?

Comment: all collections of the specific author will go into 1 array at first (as long as they are members of the array collections in author), this is not a problem as long as they are not too many like 200.000 even if they are 1000 its fine i think.With the pipeline before we would only escape the construction of a bigger array i dont think it costs alot. I dont have the data to test it or try alternatives, try it with your data, and if its slow we will see.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't reply earlier, but I only noticed now that maybe my question wasn't clear. What I try to do is get from the collection of collections all the collections of a user with also four of the most recent artworks in the collection. In this case, your aggregation assumes that in the user's documents there is a "collections" field which is not there, but it's in the artworks. Also, even if I run the query in the artworks collection, I would get the artworks and their collections. However, I need the collections and for each of them, 4 artworks. Maybe I didn't understand your solution.

Comment: dont worry i did the opposite join from what you wanted, i fixed it now, i think now does the same as your query, if you have many data, send some feedback if you can comparing those 2 queries (dont forget to make the multikey index on `artworks.collections`), i am curious if it helped, gl